# javascript regex allow only letters . - and spaces. And all should be from 2 to 256 symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a regex which matches any string, with between 2 and 256 characters, that starts with a letter, then contains any mixture of dots (`.`), hyphens (`-`), spaces and letters.

Currently, I have this regex:

```js
var regex = /^[a-z]+[\.\-\s]*$/i;
```

But I'm not sure how to have it match only 2-256 characters,

how would I do this?

Comment: http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var regex = /^[a-z][a-z.\s-]{1,255}$/i;
```